# On Mechanical Turk, how do you see the results of auto-graded qualification tests?

Tags: amazon

When you go to Manage-->Qualification Types, you can see how many workers have your qualification. But, is there some way to see a breakdown of the actual scores by person? Also, is it possible to see how many times they've taken your test if you allow retries?

Comment: Thanks for the MTurk tag. I was surprised that one didn't already exist.